# Override IOS UIWebview html manifest fallback URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, manifest

Just looking for a way to intercept the fallback URL's that are called when accessing non cached url's in an offline state using UIWebview.

When the fallback URL's are loaded into the webview in an offline state the delegate method shouldStartLoadWithRequest request is never equal to the fallback url.  I'm guessing UIWebview loads the fallback url's internally.  Is there anyway to intercept them or stop them from being loaded without editing the manifest?